# What does the dot mean in teleport command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Please tell me what dot does in this command:

```
execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~-.5 ~
```

Comment: That command looks incomplete, you only have 5 relative coordinates

Answer (score 2):

It's just a decimal number without the starting zero.
That's essentially:

```
execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~-0.5 ~
```